# Allow users to remotely modify Windows Scheduled Tasks without granting them log on rights

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

Is there any way to allow users to create/edit/delete scheduled tasks on a remote machine without allowing them to log on (remotely)? The machine is a Windows 7 (Enterprise) one or alternatively Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Are machines in a domain or standalone hosts?

Comment: @Volodymyr these machines are in a domain

Answer (score 1):

You can add users who need to modify scheduled tasks remotely to the local Administrators group via GPO (Security Filtering) and configure this GPO with not to allow interactive logon setting or alternatively you can specify on a remote host in Advanced System Settings specific user accounts which can log in.

After this is done, user then can connect to Task Scheduler by opening Task Scheduler locally and then entering name of the remote host.

[image]

Comment: This surely works, but the OPs requirement included "without granting them the right to log on", which precludes making the users members of the *Administrators* group - you effectively can't revoke administrative rights from administrators.